# update table and set max date from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to update accounts_cstm table with max date (last_buy_date_c) from another invoice_date  table.

I have tried

```
UPDATE accounts_cstm ac 
JOIN accounts a 
JOIN aos_invoices inv 
SET ac.last_buy_date_c = inv.invoice_date 
WHERE a.id = ac.id_c AND inv.billing_account_id = a.id
```

But I don't know how to implement max function in my query.

Also tried this query

```
UPDATE accounts_cstm acs 
JOIN accounts acc 
SET acs.last_buy_date_c = (SELECT MAX(inv.invoice_date) FROM aos_invoices inv JOIN accounts a 
JOIN accounts_cstm ac 
WHERE inv.billing_account_id = a.id AND ac.id_c = a.id)
```

Comment: Can you write the equivalent SELECT? If not, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dependent (correlated) subquery:

```
UPDATE accounts_cstm ac 
SET ac.last_buy_date_c = (
  SELECT MAX(inv.invoice_date)
  FROM accounts a 
  JOIN aos_invoices inv ON inv.billing_account_id = a.id
  WHERE a.id = ac.id_c -- dependent/correlated condition
)
```

Note: At least in MySQL you cannot reference the table which is being updated in the subquery. That is probably the reason, why your second query fails.

#### Update

I just realized that with `inv.billing_account_id = a.id` AND `a.id = ac.id_c` the intermediate table `accounts` doesn't need to be queried, because you can just check for `inv.billing_account_id = ac.id_c`. The query would be:

```
UPDATE accounts_cstm ac 
SET ac.last_buy_date_c = (
  SELECT MAX(inv.invoice_date)
  FROM aos_invoices inv
  WHERE inv.billing_account_id = ac.id_c -- dependent/correlated condition
)
```

The only reason to JOIN the `accounts` is to check for an existence of an account, which shouldn't be necessary in a properly designed schema with foreign keys.

Also note that you should have an index on `aos_invoices(billing_account_id)`.

Comment: Thank you, on my database with 100000 records this query already in progress about 20 minutes. But it seems that the records are updating correctly. Waiting for query to complete.

Comment: You seem not to have supporting indexes. You should have idexes on `accounts(id)` (probably primary key) and on `aos_invoices(billing_account_id)` (probably missing).

Answer (score -1):

max()  is a window function.
It must be paired using a GROUP BY.  It doenst calculate, it only see the maximum value of a certain group.

As for update syntax it should be like this

```
UPDATE table as t1,  table as t2
SET [copy values]
WHERE   t1.id = t2.id
```

No need to apply JOIN keyword on UPDATE statements.

If it is only a one time update... On this case, I recommend create a temporary table and perform the MAX there.
Then perform UPDATE between the target table and the temporary table.

Comment: I think it's technically incorrect to refer to MAX as a window function. It's an aggregate function. And there's no reason *not* to apply JOIN on UPDATE statements

Answer (score -2):

You should select max value and put it to set

```
UPDATE accounts_cstm SET last_buy_date_c = (SELECT MAX(invoice_date) FROM
```

Comment: Tried this, but getting error SQL Error (1093): Table 'acs' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for datauery

UPDATE accounts_cstm acs JOIN accounts acc SET acs.last_buy_date_c = (SELECT MAX(inv.invoice_date) FROM aos_invoices inv JOIN accounts a JOIN accounts_cstm ac WHERE inv.billing_account_id = a.id AND ac.id_c = a.id)